# readelf -s does not output full variable names

Tags: linux, elf, dwarf, readelf

I need to get the global symbols from a compiled c program file. What I use is the linux command `readelf -s filePath`  when I use that command this is what I get:

[image]

I draw a blue rectangle to show that variable names do not get displayed correctly. **they get trim after 25 characters. How can I make it display the full names?**

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add the wide switch:

```
readelf -s --wide pathOfFile
```